# How would I override a function in Scala with another function?

Tags: function, scala, foreach, overriding

In scala I have this function:

```
def handleCollision {
    walls.foreach(w => if (curPlayer.intersects(w)) {
            curPlayer.setLocation(playerStartPos._1, playerStartPos._2)
            updateLives(-1)
        })
    obstacles.foreach(o => if (curPlayer.intersects(o)) {
            curPlayer.setLocation(playerStartPos._1, playerStartPos._2)
            updateLives(-1)
        })
} // End "handleCollision"
```

What I want to do is when a player hits the key "c" in my match statement:

```
 case 'c' =>
```

I want it to call this function and override the above function so that it does not work anymore:

```
def cheatKey {
    walls.foreach(w => if (curPlayer.intersects(w)) {
            updateLives(+0)
        })
    obstacles.foreach(o => if (curPlayer.intersects(o)) {
            updateLives(+0)
        })
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by declaring a `var` to hold the default function for handling a collision like so:

```
var collisionFunction = () => {
  curPlayer.setLocation(playerStartPos._1, playerStartPos._2)
  updateLives(-1)    
}
```

Then, your handleCollision function would be changed to this:

```
def handleCollision { 
  walls.foreach(w => if (curPlayer.intersects(w)) {
    collisionFunction()
  })

  obstacles.foreach(o => if (curPlayer.intersects(o)) {
    collisionFunction()
  })
}
```

Then, when you hit your cheat condition, you would update collisionFunction like so:

```
collisionFunction = () => {
  updateLives(+0)
}
```

This is a little crude as it has a mutable variable for the function swapping, but it would work for what you are looking to do.

Comment: All answers are good, but this one is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a `var f`, which you initialize to

```
f = handleCollision
```

Then in your case statement set

```
f = cheatKey
```

And use `f` where you would have used either `cheatKey` or `handleCollision`.

This is basically the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

subclass and then:

```
override def handleCollision = {
  if (cheat) cheatKey else super.handleCollision
}
```